# how to print An object within an object - values and attributes in python

Tags: python, object

I want to print An object within an object  - values and attributes in Python
I have an Object that contains 5 attributes, when I did "dir(obj)" I got 5 attributes; I want all the values and attributes for these 5 attributes. I wrote this

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2


oba = A()


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = "value1"
        self.prop2 = "value2"
        self.obj = oba


obj = MyClass()

for attr in dir(obj):
    if not attr.startswith("__"):
        print(attr, getattr(obj, attr))
```

and this in the console:

```
obj <__main__.a object at 0x0000015657DB8C88>
prop1 value1
prop2 value2
```

I want to see:

```
obj a 1  b 2
prop1 value1
prop2 value2
```

Comment: Please show an example of what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `__str__` method to `A`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

    def __str__(self):
        return f"a {self.a} b {self.b}"
```

Although, I don't know why you want to pass through all attributes using `dir`. I would simply add `__str__` to `MyClass` also and print the object in one go, like:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

    def __str__(self):
        return f"a {self.a} b {self.b}"


oba = A()


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = "value1"
        self.prop2 = "value2"
        self.obj = oba

    def __str__(self):
        return f"MyClass(prop1={self.prop1}, prop2={self.prop2}, obj={self.obj})"


obj = MyClass()
print(obj)
```

Prints: `MyClass(prop1=value1, prop2=value2, obj=a 1 b 2)`

Comment: thanks, it is nice,  but I can't edit class A

Comment: @Ino, ohh that's unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach which uses `vars`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2


oba = A()


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = "value1"
        self.prop2 = "value2"
        self.obj = oba


obj = MyClass()

for k,v in vars(obj).items():
    print(k, end = ': ')
    try:
        print(vars(v))
    except TypeError:
        print(v)
```

Output:

```
prop1: value1
prop2: value2
obj: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: I got this error
```
E       TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```
so is not help yet

Comment: @Ino the `try...except` is designed to catch that error. If you get that error then you are trying to call the overall code on something which doesn't have objects for attributes. The solution would be to wrap the overall code in a `try ... except`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution to your problem. The output is:

```
obj a 1 b 2 
prop1 value1
prop2 value2
```

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2


oba = A()


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = "value1"
        self.prop2 = "value2"
        self.obj = oba


obj = MyClass()

for attr in dir(obj):
    if not attr.startswith("__"):
        val = getattr(obj, attr)

        if isinstance(val, A):
            print("obj", end=" ")

            for attr in dir(val):
                if not attr.startswith("__"):
                    print(attr, getattr(val, attr), end=" ")

            print()

        else:
            print(attr, val)
```

Comment: thanks, it is nice,  but What I wrote was an example
But in the original project - each attribute can be a different class, I don't know what and how it is called